# get <script> content as String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried using Javascript on demand to override cross domain problems.

So now I have something like that on my page:

```
<script id="scr1" src="{some other domain url}"></script>
```

The content of this script is a simply an array:

```
["hello", "world", "what", "where"]
```

I want to somehow get this content as string so I can eval it.

I wish I had some JS/JQuery method like

```
var v = eval($("#scr1").getContent());
```

Can you help me please?

Note: I can't use ajax as a solution.

Comment: The script tag will run automatically. You can try [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) though, which is AJAX indirectly.

Comment: Yeah I recommend this too. Try to not use Eval.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should look up JSONP.  What you want your script to return is the invocation of a callback with the data as the argument.

```
<script id="scr1" src="http://www.example.com/some/action?callback=cb" type="text/javascript></script>
```

The server side then, would produce the script contents:

```
cb( ["hello", "world", "what", "where"] );
```

Then on in your page, you'd need to have a function named `cb` that expects an array.

```
function cb(data) {
  // do something with the array
}
```

Of course, this expects the cooperation of the server to understand your callback parameter and respond appropriately.  If you control the server, that's pretty easy to do.  If not, then you'll need to use an API that is constructed to return JSONP.  The `callback` parameter is a pretty standard name for such frameworks.  If they don't have an API, then you need to proxy the request on your server, in which case you can use standard JSON.

FWIW, jQuery makes this pretty easy for APIs that expect to return JSONP.

```
$.getJSON( 'http://example.com/api/method?callback=?', data, function(result) {
     // do something with the json result
});
```

You can also use this with post/get/ajax methods as well, but [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is easier.  Note that including the callback parameter automatically tells it to use a JSONP (script) request and automatically fills in the name of the callback it creates to wrap the (anonymous) callback function in the request.

Answer (score 2):

should be possible with jquery.getScript

```
$.getScript('urlOfRemoveScript',function(script){
    var v = eval(script);
});
```

Not 100% sure this will work though.

Comment: [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) might work better for this, since the content just needs to be retrieved, not executed.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my contribution if someone really needs to find a way to read every script content.

```
  jQuery("script").each(function(){
    var scriptContent = this.innerText
    // do something with scriptContent
  })
```

Comment: I really dont understand why vote down and not share whats reason it was voted down.

Comment: Because you did not read the question. They never asked for inner data in script, they wanted contents of JS file in src=""